# Looping through levels of a factor and comparing one variable to another

Tags: r, loops, character, r-factor

I have a data.frame with one factor and two string character columns(nationality). The factor has 2662 levels each denoting a team. Teams have multiple members, thus each level has ~6 rows.

What I want to do is loop through the levels of the teams and compare a members nationality and see if this nationality is present in any of the levels the other character column. When there is a match I want a vector to be marked with 1, when there is no match I want a variable to be marked with 2.

Illustration

```
Team    N1  N2
1      JPN  US
1      US   GER
1      DNK  RUS
2      …    …
2      …    …
```

Ideally my code would register a 1 for US and a 2 for JPN

I've seen functions like split, tapply, etc... but I am having problems writing an anonymous function to achieve the goal I want:

```
tapply(Data, TEAM_ID, function () for (i in N1){if (N1 %in% N2) Identifyingvect <= 1} else {Identifyingvect <= 2})
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the tip. I tried it and it seems to work, however how do I set the value 1 for true for false? Sorry I'm pretty novice at this stuff!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be probably solved with `by`, but I prefer `data.table` for such tasks, something among these lines (btw, `tapply` is an aggregation function thus it won't work properly for assigning a value to *each* element in case there are dupes in `N1`)

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(Data)[, res := (!N1 %in% N2) + 1L, by = Team]
```

Honestly, I prefer to keep `res` logical because it's both more intuitive and easier to operate on, though in order to assign `2` to `FALSE` matches and `1` to `TRUE` matches I had to look for non-matches instead of matches and then add a `1`

Comment: Works perfectly! You're a genius and a gentleman! So res is set to 1 by default and if (!N1 %in% N2) is true then it adds one?

Comment: `res` doesn't have a default. It returns a `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector and then converted to an integer by adding `1`. Personally, like mentioned, I think you would have been better of with just `setDT(Data)[, res2 := N1 %in% N2, by = Team]`. Then you could filter by just `Data[(res2)]` if yo want to see the matched ones. Or `Data[(!res2)]` if you want to unmatched ones. Much better than `1` and `2` IMO.

Comment: That makes sense, and again it is my ignorance that would suggest doing it a more inefficient manner. One last question, if I may? How would I adapt the code to also check the N1 column for identical nationalities, in other words let's imagine that team 1 has a fourth row in the example above which was labelled US in N1, how could I check if there was another US within the team 1 in the N1 column.

Comment: You need to make a reproducible example and show your desired output.

Comment: Okay, so this is getting complicated but here's nothing. Now I have people who have the different N1 and N2, and I want to compare this to people who have same N1 and N2 to see if they have the same value as the person with the different N1 and N2. For instance, Team    N1  N2
1      India  US
1      US   GER
1      India India
2      …    …
2      …    …     In this example the 1st person in team 1 would be given a value of true because their N1 != N2 but other members of the group (whose N1 == N2) have the same nationality as them.